# Erlang regexp matching on Chinese characters

Tags: character-encoding, erlang

TL;DR:

```
25> re:run("йцу.asd", xmerl_regexp:sh_to_awk("*.*"), [{capture, none}]). 
** exception error: bad argument
     in function  re:run/3
        called as re:run([1081,1094,1091,46,97,115,100],
                         "^(.*\\..*)$",
                         [{capture,none}])
```

How to make this work? 'йцу' are characters that don't belong in a latin charset, obviously; is there a way to tell the re module or entire system to run with a different charset for "strings"?

**ORIGINAL QUESTION (for the record):**

Another "Programming Erlang" question )

in Chapter 16 there's an example about reading tags from the mp3 files. It works, great. But, there seems to be some bug in a provided module, **lib_find**, which has a function for searching a path for matching files. This is the call that works:

```
61> lib_find:files("../..", "*.mp3", true).   
["../../early/files/Veronique.mp3"]
```

and this call fails:

```
62> lib_find:files("../../..", "*.mp3", true).
** exception error: bad argument
     in function  re:run/3
        called as re:run([46,46,47,46,46,47,46,46,47,46,107,101,114,108,47,98,117,
                          105,108,100,115,47,50,48,46,49,47,111|...],
                         "^(.*\\.mp3)$",
                         [{capture,none}])
     in call from lib_find:find_files/6 (lib_find.erl, line 29)
     in call from lib_find:find_files/6 (lib_find.erl, line 39)
     in call from lib_find:files/3 (lib_find.erl, line 17)
```

Ironically, the investigation led to finding the culprit in Erlang's own installation:

> .kerl/builds/20.1/otp_src_20.1/lib/ssh/test/ssh_sftp_SUITE_data/sftp_tar_test_data_高兴

OK, this seems to mean Erlang is using a more restrictive default charset, which doesn't include **hànzì**. What are the options? Obviously, I can just ignore this and move on with my study, but I feel I can learn more from this one =) Such as - where/how can I fix the default charset? I'm a little surprised it's something other than UTF8 by default - so maybe I'm on a wrong track?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR:**

UTF-8 regexs are accessible by putting the regex pattern into unicode mode with the option `unicode`. (Note below that the string `"^(.*\\..*)$"` is the result of your call to `xmerl_regexp:sh_to_awk/1`.)

```
1> re:run("なにこれ.txt", "^(.*\\..*)$").
** exception error: bad argument
     in function  re:run/2
        called as re:run([12394,12395,12371,12428,46,116,120,116],"^(.*\\..*)$")
2> re:run("なにこれ.txt", "^(.*\\..*)$", [unicode]).
{match,[{0,16},{0,16}]}
```

And from your exact example:

```
11> re:run("йцу.asd", "^(.*\\..*)$", [unicode, {capture, none}]).       
match
```

Or

```
12> {ok, Pattern} = re:compile("^(.*\\..*)$", [unicode]).
{ok,{re_pattern,1,1,0,
                <<69,82,67,80,87,0,0,0,16,8,0,0,65,0,0,0,255,255,255,
                  255,255,255,...>>}}
13> re:run("йцу.asd", Pattern, [{capture, none}]).               
match
```

The docs for `re` are pretty long and extensive, but that's because regexs are an inherently complex subject. You can find options for compiled regexs in the docs for [`re:compile/2`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/re.html#run-3) and the options for run in the docs for [`re:run/3`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/re.html#run-3).

**Discussion**

Erlang has settled on the idea that strings, though still a list of codepoints, are all [UTF-8 everywhere](http://erlang.org/doc/man/unicode.html#type-chardata). As I work in Japan and deal with this all the time, this has come as a big relief to me because I can stop using about half of the conversion libraries I had needed in the past (yay!), but has complicated matters a bit for users of the [`string`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/string.html) module because [many operations there now perform under slightly different assumptions](http://erlang.org/doc/man/string.html#lexemes-2) (a string is still considered "flat" even if it is a deep list of grapheme clusters, so long as those clusters exist on the first level of the list).

Unfortunately, encodings are just not very easy things to deal with and UTF-8 is anything but simple once you step out of the most common representations -- so much of this is a work in progress. I can tell you with confidence, though, that dealing with UTF-8 data in binary, string, deep list, and `io_data()` forms, whether file names, file data, network data, or user input from WX or web forms works as expected once you read the unicode, regex and string docs.

But that is, of course, a lot of stuff to get familiar with. 99% of the time things will work as expected if you decode everything incoming from outside as UTF-8 using [`unicode:characters_to_list/1`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/unicode.html#characters_to_list-1) and [`unicode:characters_to_binary/1`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/unicode.html#characters_to_binary-1), and specify binary strings as [`utf8` binary types](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#id83099) everywhere:

```
3> UnicodeBin = <<"この文書はUTF-8です。"/utf8>>.
<<227,129,147,227,129,174,230,150,135,230,155,184,227,129,
  175,85,84,70,45,56,227,129,167,227,129,153,227,128,130>>
4> UnicodeString = unicode:characters_to_list(UnicodeBin).  
[12371,12398,25991,26360,12399,85,84,70,45,56,12391,12377,
 12290]
5> io:format("~ts~n", [UnicodeString]).
この文書はUTF-8です。
ok
6> re:run(UnicodeString, "UTF-8", [unicode]).
{match,[{15,5}]}
7> re:run(UnicodeBin, "UTF-8", [unicode]).   
{match,[{15,5}]}
8> unicode:characters_to_binary(UnicodeString).
<<227,129,147,227,129,174,230,150,135,230,155,184,227,129,
  175,85,84,70,45,56,227,129,167,227,129,153,227,128,130>>
9> unicode:characters_to_binary(UnicodeBin).   
<<227,129,147,227,129,174,230,150,135,230,155,184,227,129,
  175,85,84,70,45,56,227,129,167,227,129,153,227,128,130>>
```

Comment: oh man, at first I was surprised with the binary strings - <<"huh what is this for, can't you just use strings">> ... but when I thought about "stuff" being a fake string anyway, while binaries are honest, it all made sense.

Comment: @alexakarpov So "binaries being honest" is a bit of a lie (binary representation means that the "match" above matches the 15th *byte*, but that's not the 15th *lexeme*), matching "characters" is also a lie because 1 char does not mean 1 lexeme. Lexemes are the only truth, and that's part of why this gets so confusing (since nobody wants to use 4 bytes to represent 1 [A-Z] ASCII char!). So we have lexemes, and those might be single codepoints or clusters or a mix of whatever! Ah! But that sucks less than any other alternative, so we're stuck.